# App keeps crashing when trying to request webpage

Tags: java, android

I have some extremely simple code here:

```
    public void test(View v) {
        try {
            new URL("http://test.com/index.php?lat=0&long=1").openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Url Exception" + e);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I press a button linked to test, it crashes instantly.
What is the problem?

Error code here: http://pastebin.com/xEJwWhD1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

**Posibility 2**
This is probably due to the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception that was introduced in Honeycomb. To fix this you should do all your network-y stuff in a seperate thread (you can use an `AsyncTask` for convienence).

For more information you can read this blog post: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NetworkOnMainThread exception I guess. If you try to make a network call on the main thread, even though you add the permissions you get this exception. You need to use Asynctask or libraries like volley for this one.